# Calling ASP.NET Web Service with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest

I have a web service defined as:

```
[ScriptService]
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [WebMethod]
    public IEnumerable<string> getUsers()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new questionanswerEntities())
            {
                var users = context.users.ToList();
                string[] result = new string[users.Count];

                for (int i = 0; i < users.Count; ++i)
                {
                    user u = users[i];
                    result[i] = u.id + " " + u.name + " " + u.email;
                }

                return result;
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
        catch (EntityException ex) 
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I have published this service to my localhost and I am able to call and test it with a browser and the result is:

```
<ArrayOfstring>
    <string>1 Olcay aaa@aaa.com</string>
    <string>2 Mukaddes aaa@aaa.com</string>
    <string>3 Saduman sadumanertas@gmail.com</string>
    <string>4 Bernam bernella@bb.com</string>
    <string>8 Bernella bernella@gmail.com</string>
    <string>9 Bernella bernella@gmail.com</string>
    <string>10 Bernella bernella@gmail.com</string>
    <string>11 Bernella bernella@gmail.com</string>
    <string>12 Bernella bernella@gmail.com</string>
    <string>13 Bernella bernella@gmail.com</string>
    <string>14 lala loorrrrr@gmail.com</string>
    <string>15 lala loorrrrr@gmail.com</string>
</ArrayOfstring>
```

What I need is to call this service from JavaScript. I am trying this:

```
function callService() {
    var url = "http://localhost:1903/QATest/login/getUsers";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var response = xhr.responseText;
        console.log("XHR - onload - Result of getUsers: " + response);
        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = "Response: " + response;
    };
    xhr.onerror = function () {
        console.log("XHR - onerror - Web servis cagirilirken hata olustu!");
    };
    xhr.send();
};
```

But getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:1903/QATest/login/getUsers. Invalid HTTP status code 405
```

My ASP.NET service is hosted on my localhost and client side codes are hosted at my remote host at 'www.olcayertas.com'.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I have started this project as ASP.NET Web application and then selected Web API option. So there is no any asmx files as web service projects. But [Exposing Web Services to Client Script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) suggests adding following to client side for ASP.NET web pages:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="scriptManager">
  <Services>
    <asp:ServiceReference
       path="~/WebServices/SimpleWebService.asmx" />
  </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

But I have to call my services using JavaScript from a PHP page.
How can I do that?

Comment: Exposing Web Services to Client Script is just to get the necessary JavaScript onto the ASP.Net page output to help with the XHR. The JavaScript you have posted seems ok and should work from PHP. You are getting the 405 response so the request is being sent you just need to configure the web service to allow the response.

Answer (score 1):

You are being blocked because you are attempting a [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) which fails because of the [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

You will need to configure [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) on you local host to allow requests from 'www.olcayertas.com'. With IIS you might just need to add this to the `web.config`;

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
```

Be careful though as this opens up your service to requests from any domain. You should probably only allow requests from 'www.olcayertas.com' if you know this is the only consumer of your web service.

Comment: Where exactly should I add <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> in web.config?

Comment: @Mukaddes a quick google for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin iis` gives you this as the first link; http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html which shows the section to add it to.

Comment: I have moved my client side codes to my localhost to get rid of cross domain problem but I am still getting the same error. I have updated my question. Could you look at it again?

Comment: @Mukaddes Your JavaScript makes a request to localhost on port 1903 which I assume is the test ASP.Net server from Visual Studio? How are you running PHP? Unless that is also accessible on localhost port 1903 you will still break the same origin policy. Did you update your `web.config` so it allows requests from a different origin?